# HTTP request no response in Chrome Version 48

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, http

Earlier, chrome upgrading to version 48.

Some never before had a problem (in earlier versions, such as 47), such as pages and ajax request can not return data.

Start ajax request is no response, return "this request has no preview available", but only the individual ajax request, there is a page has five ajax request, only one of the two ajax no return, but the remaining three one can work.

Today, we found that the request pages directly blocking the entire page could not be loaded.

Or more, on Firefox no problems, normal page, ajax request properly.

I began to wonder whether it is after you upgrade to chrome version 48, in order to reduce memory consumption, blocking part of a normal request.

So, does anybody know the cause of the problem and how to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,48.0.2564.103 m has fix it.

just see Comment 16 in
[Sync ajax call get 200 code but empty body when the server returns 304 Not Modified](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582365#c16)